# Exercise in high school number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is as follows: If $n$ is less than $m$, show that $(n+1)^3+\dots+m^3 = ((m-n)(m+n+1)(n^2+n+m^2+m))/4$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$$\sum_{a=1}^ba^3=\big(\frac{b(b+1)}{2}\big)^2$$

Now evaluate two expressions,

FIRST

$$\sum_{k=1}^mk^3=\big(\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\big)^2$$

SECOND

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\big)^2$$

Now find FIRST - SECOND

You will get $$\sum_{k=n+1}^mk^3$$ which is the given expression.